# How can I create dynamic/conditional navigation with Jetpack Navigation?

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

I've come across an interesting problem with trying to accomplish dynamic or conditional navigation with the Jetpack Navigation library.

The goal I have in mind is to be able to continue using the `nav_graph.xml` to manage the overall navigation graph, but simultaneously allow for conditional navigation based on some factors.

I have included some code below that shows where my solution is headed. The problem is that it inherently requires a lot of maintenance for future conditional logic to work.

I really want the `navigateToDashboard` function in the example to be able to be executed with either no parameters, or parameters that rarely change. For instance, instead of passing `NavDirections`, maybe passing some identifier that let's the `navigateToDashboard` function know which `NavDirections` to return.

Code for the class managing the conditional logic.

```
class DynamicNavImpl(private val featureFlagService: FeatureFlagService) : DynamicNav {

    override fun navigateToDashboard(navDirectionsMap: Map<Int, NavDirections>): NavDirections {
        val destinationIdRes = if (featureFlagService.isDashboardV2Enabled()) {
            R.id.dashboardV2Fragment
        } else {
            R.id.dashboardFragment
        }

        return navDirectionsMap[destinationIdRes] ?: handleNavDirectionsException(destinationIdRes)
    }

    private fun handleNavDirectionsException(destinationIdRes: Int): Nothing {
        throw IllegalStateException("Destination $destinationIdRes does not have an accompanying set of NavDirections. Are you sure you added NavDirections for it?")
    }
}
```

Call site examples

```
navigate(
        dynamicNav.navigateToDashboard(
                mapOf(
                        Pair(R.id.dashboardFragment, PhoneVerificationFragmentDirections.phoneVerificationToDashboard()),
                        Pair(R.id.dashboardV2Fragment, PhoneVerificationFragmentDirections.phoneVerificationToDashboardV2())
                )
        )
)
```

```
navigate(
        dynamicNav.navigateToDashboard(
                mapOf(
                        Pair(R.id.dashboardFragment, EmailLoginFragmentDirections.emailLoginToDashboard()),
                        Pair(R.id.dashboardV2Fragment, EmailLoginFragmentDirections.emailLoginToDashboardV2())
                )
        )
)
```

Looking at the call site, you could see how this could be problematic. If I ever want to add a new potential destination, let's say `dashboardV3Fragment`, then I'd have to go to each call site and add another `Pair`.

This almost defeats the purpose of having the `DynamicNavImpl` class. So this is where I am stuck. I want to be able to encapsulate the various variables involved in deciding what destination to go to, but it seems with how `NavDirections` are implemented, I'm not able to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I went between a few different approaches, and I landed on something that still doesn't feel ideal, but works for my use case.

I completely abandoned the idea of using a central dynamic navigation manager. Instead, I decided on having a "redirect" or "container" `Fragment` that decides what `Fragment` to show.

So here's the new code inside of the `DashboardRedirectFragment`

```
childFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(
                R.id.dashboard_placeholder,
                if (featureFlagService.isDashboardV2Enabled()) {
                    DashboardV2Fragment.newInstance()
                } else {
                    DashboardFragment.newInstance()
                }
        ).commit()
```

The way I'm using this is by registering a new destination in my nav graph called `dashboardRedirectFragment`, and anything in the graph that needs access to the dashboard use the `dashboardRedirectFragment` destination.

This fully encapsulates the dynamic navigation logic in the redirect `Fragment`, and allows me to continue using my nav graph as expected.